# Проверка на добавление файла в папку

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

У меня есть сервис, который должен постоянно проверять определенную папку, и при добавлении какого либо файла в папку он должен совершать определенные действия. Вопрос: как поймать событие добавления файла в папку?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь всё работает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взял ответ из ссылки в комментарии к моему вопросу:

```
observer = new FileObserver("путь до папки") { 

             @Override
             public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
                if(event == FileObserver.CREATE){ 

                 "какое-либо действие при добавлении файла"

                 }
             }
         };
observer.startWatching();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 File file = new File("C:\\asd.txt");
    boolean exists = file.exists();
    if(exists){
        //код
    }esle{
        //код
    }
```

этот код проверяет есть ли определенный файл(asd.txt) в папке.

Comment: Спасибо, но данный метод для меня не подходит, т.к. название файла заранее не известно + тут только проверяется существование файла, а не отслеживается события при добавлении файла в папку.